# Eclipse plugin: equivalent to org.eclipse.ui.startup in command line

Tags: eclipse, plugins, rcp

I want to be aware when the eclipse framework is available but my plugin can be used via command line so registering to org.eclipse.ui.startup is not an option.

Is there any other way ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you mean running without the UI you write a 'headless rcp' see for example [here](https://codeandme.blogspot.com/2012/02/creating-headless-application.html)

Comment: Thanks. Actually I know how to make a headless RCP. What I don't know is how to start myplugin after the eclipse core framework is started ?

Comment: You don't do anything. The core framework is already set up with IApplication.start is called.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer